# Simple button isotope filtering example please?

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I've been looking everywhere for an isotope example I can actually understand, that isn't well above my head!

and preferably without multidimensional arrays? :|

Here is the jsfiddle of what I have currently https://jsfiddle.net/LL39kwue/2/

```
var $grid = $('#grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.item',
  layoutMode: 'packery',
});
$(function() {
  var $buttons = $('#filter-menu button');
  $buttons.on('click', function() {
    var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $grid.isotope({
      filter: filterValue
    });
  });
});
```

I just want to be able to select more than one filter option at a time, eg. .category-1, .category-2

I've tried already to combine mine with this checkbox example http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/qaEsi

```
$(function() {
  var $buttons = $('#filter-menu button');
  var filters = [];
  $buttons.on('click', function() {
    var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    filters.push(filterValue);
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
  filters = filters.join(', ');
  $grid.isotope({
    filter: filters
  });
});
```

But that returns: Uncaught TypeError: filters.push is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

the issue I was having was using filters = filters.join(', ');

It needed to be

```
something_else = filters.join(', ');
$grid.isotope({
  filter: something_else
});
```

I'm not sure how you're meant to figure that out from the error: Uncaught TypeError: filters.push is not a function :|

Working jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/8mj4nftv/2/